# Numerical enigma

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, literature

> My whole, composed of 19 letters, is a quotation from Milton's
>   "Paradise Lost".
>
> My 13, 7, 16, 18 is to be peevish, to worry.
>
> My 15, 3, 5, 9 is broad.
>
> My 4, 12, 19, 14 is deprivation.
>
> My 11, 6, 17, 8 is observed.
>
> My 10, 1, 2 is a carpenter's instrument.

---

*Source (this is not intended to be used to look up the answer, but is posted under [the policy on plagiarism of the Puzzle Stack Exchange website](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)):*

> Source: The Queenslander (discontinued in 1939), without any specific author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote is:

> "A wilderness of sweets"

Solution:

> ```
>  Character:                             = Clue
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
>              r           f     e   t    = fret
>
>      i   d       e           w          = wide
>
>        l               o   s         s  = loss
>
>            e   n     s           e      = seen
>
>  a w               s                    = saw
>
>  So in total:
>  a w i l d e r n e s s o f s w e e t s
> ```

Comment: Oh darn, I shouldn't have spent that time typing out everything. :)

Answer (score 4):

> A wilderness of sweets

13, 7, 16, 18:

> fret

15, 3, 5, 9:

> wide

4, 12, 19, 14:

> loss

11, 6, 17, 8:

> seen

10, 1, 2:

> saw